# Repeat a model 100 times per individual

Tags: r, function, loops, apply, sapply

I want to repeat a model (GAM) 100 times per individual, in R. Then I want to perform model averaging of these models and obtain the averaged coefficients, per individual. I have a dataset with response + explanatory variables for a group of individuals (dist_FS.utm).

```
> head(dist_FS.utm)
   id min_dist_to_FS used min_dist_exp    x_utm   y_utm
1  41       918.8052    1    0.4581917 465801.8 5033858
2  41      1863.5125    1    0.7114719 465682.4 5041281
3  41       830.5054    1    0.4253230 460491.4 5040223
4  41      3381.4481    1    0.8951711 464405.4 5039687
5  41      3392.7368    1    0.8959575 464442.1 5059669
6  41       654.1306    1    0.3535795 464495.0 5061919
```

I've checked some questions like: [simulate a linear model 100 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554558/simulate-a-linear-model-100-times) and [How to repeat a process N times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955558/how-to-repeat-a-process-n-times) but I still didn't manage to do it.

So far, I've done this:

```
for (i in (unique(dist_FS.utm$id))) {
        db <- dist_FS.utm[dist_FS.utm$id==i,]
        gam_id <- gam(used~min_dist_exp + s(x_utm, y_utm), data = db, family=binomial)
        gam_id_100 <- t(sapply(1:100,gam_id))
        a <- model.avg(gam_id_100)
        }
```

And I obtain this error:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'gam_id' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Which I think it is because `gam_id` is not a function (https://www.guru99.com/r-apply-sapply-tapply.html). I was trying to write this as a function and then use replicate(), but I am not sure how, because I need to split by individual... (I'm not very familiar with functions and loops, but saw that here: https://nicercode.github.io/guides/repeating-things/)

1. Does anyone know how can I do this efficiently?
2. Based on the code I wrote above, even if it would have worked, I don't think I would get the average coefficients **per individual**, right? If so, how can I get that? Maybe I have to store them somewhere...

**EDIT**

> ```
> >dput(head(dist_FS.utm,30))
> structure(list(X = c(1L, 15L, 25L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
> 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
> 55L, 56L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 73L), animals_id = c(41L, 
> 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
> 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
> 41L, 41L, 41L), min_dist_to_FS = c(918.80522737075, 1863.51246503695, 
> 830.505382951001, 3381.44807737323, 3392.73683300527, 654.130586700104, 
> 2566.31958442098, 1053.65311284759, 966.144306603196, 873.484749339232, 
> 121.806430036914, 1387.64623589338, 1004.18377421608, 1549.18381508086, 
> 1419.58318230344, 1467.30800101015, 1982.15665056485, 1574.24870423625, 
> 1649.08689860009, 1509.82936705109, 1522.69465586994, 1549.32812543367, 
> 1433.34459545157, 1399.18930656071, 1516.77860478692, 1517.30360715202, 
> 1535.19659260561, 1527.56075938311, 1507.97021104668, 955.188805770983
> ), used = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
> 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
> 1L), min_dist_exp = c(0.458191730619659, 0.711471904832608, 0.425322974299617, 
> 0.895171109000169, 0.895957464432406, 0.353579527899345, 0.819447766862565, 
> 0.504796567587344, 0.475032147975436, 0.441563479599525, 0.0780321158438149, 
> 0.60369059194633, 0.488184247651747, 0.644171214938928, 0.612043470340838, 
> 0.624198588744711, 0.733424689932805, 0.650070609306066, 0.667109263467795, 
> 0.634707248445273, 0.63782846850107, 0.6442054635922, 0.615588176935089, 
> 0.606730152341633, 0.636396514046123, 0.63652381717982, 0.640835984546634, 
> 0.639002059809323, 0.634253983612545, 0.471181990354149), x_utm = c(455801.848652911, 
> 455682.436631772, 450491.389615233, 454405.43316214, 454442.094012587, 
> 454495.000195656, 455008.476539838, 449097.624664053, 450540.707026459, 
> 450500.924335471, 449766.142753517, 448660.380605766, 448291.700201206, 
> 447688.093883708, 447676.546228742, 447828.232148529, 451793.759557934, 
> 447638.292913575, 447576.821010766, 447710.347453009, 447691.498899187, 
> 447679.063697279, 447658.862064349, 447704.743534774, 447700.077591867, 
> 447683.441775526, 447696.249109853, 447715.294788822, 447692.191785761, 
> 449126.687863692), y_utm = c(5043858.23523823, 5051281.39009194, 
> 5050222.99885332, 5049686.7739777, 5049669.10780019, 5041919.21100737, 
> 5046290.39022494, 5048739.43310135, 5050065.94922413, 5050163.4816897, 
> 5050810.6018219, 5051476.22456451, 5050628.56392999, 5048652.92037187, 
> 5048857.81952291, 5048635.6397179, 5050709.27628448, 5048667.78083257, 
> 5048623.8530378, 5048686.25515273, 5048686.96825384, 5048661.69552229, 
> 5048857.78968914, 5048855.73937433, 5048686.70765026, 5048702.95718389, 
> 5048664.51836415, 5048656.5817114, 5048707.32827632, 5045708.60831853
> )), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
> ```

Comment: Is `X` the `id` used for build the models? So for each `id` you want 100 models?

Comment: @Duck its the "id" column, it had another name, my bad. They are all numbers, 7 in total (39-45)

Comment: Could you please `dput()` your data correctly and include that variable? I know how to solve your issue!

Comment: @Duck what do you mean by dput()? Sorry, I am not familiar with that function. Should I post the outcome of that? In the meantime I've updated the question, it has the correct name of the columns.

Comment: Yes please `dput(head(dist_FS.utm,30))` copy and paste into the question by editing it.

Comment: @Duck done! let me know if you meant something different please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) that can subset a data frame by one or more factors and pass subsets into a method. For the method, specify `function` in `sapply` or use its wrapper, `replicate`, which expects no input parameter but re-runs any expression n times.

Also, instead of `model.avg` extract the specific coefficient from `gam` model object and then average across all 100 results. Do note: you do not specify which exact coefficient to run average. Below extracts only `min_dist_exp` term.

```
gam_id_avg_coeff_list <- by(dist_FS.utm, dist_FS.utm$animals_id, function(sub) {

     gam_formula <- used ~ min_dist_exp + s(x_utm, y_utm)

     gam_mod_100 <- replicate(100, {
                       mod <- summary(gam(gam_formula, data=sub, family=binomial))
                       mod$coefficients["min_dist_exp", "Estimate"]     # EXTRACT SPECIFIC COEFF
                    })
        
     # ALTERNATIVELY WITH sapply
     # gam_mod_100 <- sapply(1:100, function(i) {
     #                  mod <- summary(gam(gam_formula, data=sub, family=binomial))
     #                  mod$coefficients["min_dist_exp", "Estimate"]    # EXTRACT SPECIFIC COEFF
     #                })
        
     return(mean(gam_mod_100, na.rm=TRUE))        # RETURN MEAN OF COEFFICIENTS
})

gam_id_avg_coeff_list

# CONVERT TO NAMED VECTOR
gam_id_avg_coeff_vec <- c(gam_id_avg_coeff_list)

# CONVERT TO NAMED MATRIX    
gam_id_avg_coeff_matrix <- matrix(gam_id_avg_coeff_list, 
                                  dimnames = list(names(gam_id_avg_coeff_list), "mean_100"))
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, but I still got a warning message in the first part (until the return of the mean), which created then NA's in the "gam_id_avg_coeff_list". The warning message I got is: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(gam_mod_100) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Seems like some coefficients return NAs. Use `na.rm=TRUE` arg in `mean`. If all 100 iterations return NA, check your model results by removing `mean` call at the end or return all coefficients without `[` extraction.